# USB Audio Interface not listed after installing nVidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, hdmi

After installing nVidia additional drivers (319) my Fast Track Pro soundcard suddently disappeared from the list of the devices in the "sound" settings window, the thing is when i excute "aplay -l" there are additional sound devices that are not showing like the nVidia HDMI one, any help is highly appreciated, i want to get the sound working again, i tried doing force-reload and whole bunch of other stuff but with no luck, i'll be lurking around here hoping for an answer.